# Problem with keyup and shift+tab

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a small jQuery form routine designed to help a user fill in a group of bank sort code fields. There are 3 fields - when the user has filled in 2 numbers in one field, the cursor is automatically focus() on the next field.

However the problem arises if the user decides to shift+tab back to the previous field. If this field already contains 2 characters, the cursor doesn't stay within that field but jumps forward again.

HTML:

```
<div class="formItem sortCode clearfix">
  <input type="text" maxlength="2">
  <input type="text" maxlength="2">
  <input type="text" maxlength="2">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var $sortCollection = $('.sortCode input');

$('.sortCode input').keyup(function(event) {

  var sortValue = $(this).val();            
  var sortPosition = $sortCollection.index(this);       

  if (!(event.keyCode == 9 && event.shiftKey)) {
    if (sortValue.length == 2 && sortPosition != 2) {
      sortPosition += 1;
      $sortCollection.eq(sortPosition).focus().select();
    }
  }
});
```

I have a feeling the issue is to do with the keyup event being triggered when the shift key is released but I'm not sure. Please could someone take a look.

Comment: since you're new, go ahead and mark this question as answered by clicking the little 'check' next to the answer you like.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
if (!(event.keyCode == 16 || event.keyCode == 9)) { 
    if (sortValue.length == 2 && sortPosition !== 2) {
      sortPosition += 1;
      $sortCollection.eq(sortPosition).focus().select();
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks very much. But what is different about using event.keyCode == 16 to event.shiftKey? Cheers.

Comment: I'm not sure. I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work with `event.shiftKey`. But I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to ignore shift key click, just add

```
if (event.keyCode == 16) return;
```

after

```
$('.sortCode input').keyup(function(event) {
```

note: this will not affect event.shiftKey

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes event.keyCode == 16 did the trick!

Comment: Took me hours to find out it was the dumb shift key, THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.formItem input[type=text]').focus(function(){
     if ($(this).length == 2 ) {
          $(this).next('.formItem input[type=text]').focus();
     }
});
```

Try to work this into your code, the keystrokes are not checked but the focus is controlled by the value of the input box. If the input box is brought into focus has a length of 2 then the next input box is brought into focus. This is should fall through until an input box that is not a length of two is found.

Comment: i think the problem he's having is the user not being able to edit what the typed with a shift+tab. therefore, this wouldn't be any better.

Comment: Yes that's right. Getting the cursor to jump to the next field if the current field had a length of 2 wasn't the problem. The issue was if the user shift-tabs back to a field where there are already 2 characters. I couldn't get the cursor to stay in that field.